# Azure database - Schema design rules

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a simple "use case", imagine I wish to clone the Facebook application with Xamarin & Azure.

After reading this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/social-media-apps

I noticed that I can store my datas into a set of collections/document (SQL API).

But when I have to handle millions of relationships, it does not work, I have to use a Graph API database !

So, for this I need to create a database on Azure, here is what I will do for now :

1 - One Cosmos DB database - with SQL API (Collection) with :
  a) A collection for user
  b) A collection for publication

2 - One Comos DB database - with Gremlin API (Graph) with :
  a) A graph to manage the relationships between a user and a publication (ie. user A like publication B)

So, the SQL API database will manage all the records, and the Gremlin one for 
all the complexes relationships.

So, I have a few questions:
1) Do I really need 2 unconnected database ? Or it is a bad design ?
Because each time I add a user, I need to add a document in the collection,
but also a vertex ! It is a double management !

2) When I insert a document into a collection, it generate an "id" with a 
GUID key automatically. Can I use this ID as a key for my vertices ?

Maybe a user and a publication can have the same GUID ? and so, in my graph
I don't know if my vertices is a user or a publication ?

Is there another way to manage this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Krysalid. Why you want to create 2 database for your situation? Per my understanding, you could choose SQL API or Graph API.

***SQL API:***

Create user collection and pub collection.If you want to query what publications the user likes, just store pub id array in user document.

```
{
  "user":"jay",
  "likePubArray":
     [{"pubId"："A"},{"pubId"："B"}]    
}
```

If you also want bidirectional query, please store user id array in pub document.

***Graph API:***

Create user vertex and pub vertex and add target property in vertex.

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks @JayGon, please refer to this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/social-media-apps . The explain that when you have a lot of relationships (several thousands to milions) it is not manageable with SQL API ! Just read the "NO SQL Road" ... they explain why :-)